# error c2059: syntax error: '('

Tags: c++, goto

I don't understand this error it's written the exact same in the tutorial but my one generates an error.

```
#include "drawEngine.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

DrawEngine::DrawEngine(int xSize, int ySize)
{
    screenWidth = xSize;
    screenHeight = ySize;

    //set cursor visibility to false

    map = 0;
    cursorVisibility(false);
}

DrawEngine::~DrawEngine()
{
    //set cursor visibility to true
    cursorVisibility(true);
}

int DrawEngine::createSprite(int index, char c)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < 16)
    {
        spriteImage[index] = c;
        return index;
    }

    return -1;
}


void DrawEngine::deleteSprite(int index)
{
    //in this implementation we don't need it
}

void DrawEngine::drawSprite(int index, int posx, int posy)
{
    //go to the correct location
    gotoxy(posx, posy);
    //draw the image with cout
    cout << spriteImage[index];
}

void DrawEngine::eraseSprite(int posx, int posy)
{
    gotoxy(posx, posy);
    cout << ' ';
}
void DrawEngine::setMap(char **data)
{
    map = data;
}

void DrawEngine::createBackgroundTile(int index, char c)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < 16)
    {
        tileImage[index] = c;
    }
}
void DrawEngine::drawBackground(void)
{
    if (map)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++)
        {
            goto(0, y); // This generates the error

            for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
            {

                cout << tileImage[map[x][y]];
            }
        }
    }
}

void DrawEngine::gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE output_handle;
    COORD pos;

    pos.X = x;
    pos.Y = y;

    output_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output_handle, pos);
}

void DrawEngine::cursorVisibility(bool visibility)
{
    HANDLE output_handle;
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cciInfo;

    cciInfo.dwSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO);
    cciInfo.bVisible = visibility;

    output_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleCursorInfo(output_handle, &cciInfo);
}
```

Comment: what line does it claim the error is on

Comment: You have to mention what line number this occurred on (wrt the code you just pasted)

Comment: as a side note, you might want to only copy the smallest, relevant piece of code that reproduces the error next time. It's much easier to read four lines that are specific to a problem than 50 that happen to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you meant to write `gotoxy(0, y)` instead of `goto(0, y)`.

`goto` is a C++ keyword which jumps to a label, for example:

```
home:
goto home;    // Loops forever
```

Don't use it, though, it's too easy to create spaghetti code.

Comment: It's an unusual error message for a wrong function name because `goto` is a keyword ;)

Comment: It's goto _label_. _label_ can't contain '('.

Comment: Also, if you are expecting a C or C++ compiler to help you write code, you're using the wrong language. You are to be grateful that the compiler doesn't just throw a stack dump at you.

Comment: @Hugh: You mean you don't *like* debugging compiler errors with templated classes? :P

Comment: I mean that when I started programming with C the compilers _did_ die dramatically when they encountered something like a mismatched brace.

Answer (score 0):

The `goto(0, y)` should probably be `gotoxy(0, y)`. `goto` is a reserved keyword in C and cannot be used as a function name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `gotoxy`. `goto` is something else entirely.